# How to Choose a Doctoral Program in Theology?

Tags: resource-request, non-denominational, seminary

I have long considered a ThD (from the time I started my MDiv) and already have a research interest (in Pastoral Ministry) in mind. I was going to go to my denomination's seminary and pay the cost myself. However, I've just been offered a full scholarship to another school (a non-denominational secular University program).

To be honest I wanted the ThD for mainly vanity reasons (I don't intend on a research or teaching career) and getting one from my denomination's seminary may give me a tad more prestige at church councils etc. But it's a cost I'm not going to recoup as a pastor.

How does one choose a Doctoral program in this case?

To make this question more objective, are there articles / books offering pastoral career guidance in a Protestant & non-denominational church setting for a ThD / PhD applicant, of **the pros/cons of getting a doctorate in theology from a secular university** (like Harvard or Princeton) vs. **denominational/evangelical seminary** (like Fuller, Asbury, Baylor or WTS)?

Comment: I fear that the "question" as it stands may be closed for being opinion-based. (see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)). If you could [edit] it to be more objective, it could make for a good question.

Comment: I think this is a good question, not one that we commonly hit on on the site, but the original intent was to help with ministry-type questions and I think this is a good sort of question to try to answer objectively, not just ask a pastor.  I am going to remove that last line though!

Comment: Welcome to C.SE.  I agree with @PeterTurner that this can potentially be a good question, but needs to be phrased in a way that can be answered objectively but *still* able to help your personal situation.  Since you're new, I'm attempting an edit so this question can stay, which you (or other seasoned users) can edit further.

Comment: @TeddyBear I highly encourage you to email current/retired professors who have long-time experience not only in academia, but dealing with elders, denominational politics, etc. such as Roger Olson (who is approachable via his blog/email).  Also, if Pastoral Ministry (or is it more specific: Pastoral Studies / Care / Leadership / Counseling?) is your research interest, how about researching which programs are excellent in that area?  One of my friends went to Biola to get PhD in education from their seminary because they are in the top 3 in Christian education.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I was hoping to look at the intersection of historical spiritual direction with Christian spirituality

Comment: "To be honest I wanted the ThD for mainly vanity reasons" That's a concern by itself. Such an investment in time means that this study should be part of your ministry, and therefore you should in some way be sent by your church. So you should be seeing what they think. Now they may not be able to answer this question, but they should be at least approving of your desire to study more.

Comment: @curiousdannii I agree. My church has policy - commits ministers to CPE.  The problem: most ordained ministers have BTh only while others (like myself) have considerable secular education and then a MDiv. Where to pitch CPE is difficult question. You have a choice go a long with what's offered or set about your own agenda and submit evidence every 3 years. Being "sent" by the church would imply they, in some financial way, support the choice. Unfortunately I'm past my prime to be considered for church sponsored formal Ed - current position is ceiling. 20 yrs younger they would invest.

Comment: @TeddyBear 1/2 I'm in IT by profession but interested in academic theology and spirituality to sort things out (avoid false teaching) and to broaden horizon so I have the tools for using all my intellect and emotion in Godly ways for myself, my family, friends at work and at church.  While initially the interest is driven by curiosity (or obeying the unconscious desire for the transcendentals) by conscience and wisdom I have to put these projects under the law of love which due to my unique situation (like everyone else) will dictate how I should spend time, energy, and money.

Comment: @TeddyBear 2/2 Putting myself in your shoes, I can symphatize with your research interest and rejoice in getting the scholarship.  But given my pastoral responsibilities I would feel I also need to consider the needs of my sheep and the church / denomination so what I would learn can be applied there beyond the vanity as "perks".  Because after satisfying my intellectual desires and my own spiritual needs, as a Christian I would want others to share the joy that I experience (like I, as a CS Lewis fan wants to become his advocate starting with reading and discussing his books to my kids).

Comment: @TeddyBear My pastor is on a leave of absence for recuperation and discernment for his next step (he may resign).  He is a genuine pastor and my family is praying for him every day so he can find a place where he can put his whole heart to serve God in all his capacities, intellectually and emotionally.  Pastoral ministry is very hard.  So I would think the question you may consider at this later stage of career: which doctorate program can enable you to find motivation and satisfaction so your own joy can be infectious to the people you want to serve in spiritual direction?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Part of 3 yr report is to say what education youve done AND how it's made you a better pastor. Church defines CPE 'the development of personal & pastoral identity & the growth of professional competence as a minister". When I used "vanity" I meant that I don't intend on research/teaching, & I don't see the intellectual challenge provided by church CPE. Each person has different life experience learning, formal Ed & intellectual abilities. Most my age would just go along with church provided CPE, knowing their professional ceiling has been met. PhD is a personal challenge.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple In the church significant prestige is placed on PhD(Systematic Theology), Pastoral Theology is seen as the "poor relation" but I chose it deliberately because I think it is the area through which my "own joy can be infectious to the people I want to serve" in my overall ministry. It's not about promotion in the church it's about serving my people more effectively.

Comment: @TeddyBear Now that I understand more what you mean by "vanity", speaking from my own observation of myself of finding intellectual challenge important (not in a nerdy way, but what I believe is inherent human desire for larger truth), if that aspect of humanity is very important for you (having constant yearning for years) then I would do it for the sake of truth and maybe God opens door for later application of what you learn.  I would think a spiritual director very much needs to take care of himself/herself well to take care of others.

Comment: @TeddyBear Sounds like a straightforward decision then. If historical spiritual direction is the form of spiritual direction that you find will be more conducive for you to provide your sheep then it makes sense to choose the program that is better in that area.  I feel more pastors need more skills in spiritual direction than in systematic theology, so I think you made a good decision there.

Answer (score 1):

*"How does one choose a Doctoral program in this case?"*

One chooses in this case the same as in every other: by seeking God's direction through prayer, and perhaps fasting, and through study of God's Word.

No one here can give a proper answer as to what you should do.  We might suggest schools we know about and have liked, but even these suggestions could never hope to take the place of knowing what God wants for you to do.

The Bible is filled with examples of people asking God what to do--and they each found His will for them in varying and unique ways.  For some, God may give a vision or dream, like in the case of Joseph who was told to go ahead and marry Mary, and later, to take her and the babe to Egypt.  For some, God may give a physical sign or symbol, like in the case of Gideon's wet or dry fleece.  For some, God will send an angel to bar the way, as happened to Balaam (who afterward stubbornly pushed for his own way anyhow).  For some, they may hear a whispering in the trees, as did David (see 2 Samuel 5:24).

James 1:5 gives us a promise that we can claim when seeking God's guidance.

> If any of you lack wisdom, let him ask of God, that giveth to all men
> liberally, and upbraideth not; and it shall be given him. (James 1:5,
> KJV)

But this verse is followed up with "But let him ask in faith, nothing wavering." (vs. 6).  When we ask according to His will, God is happy to lead us.

> The steps of a good man are ordered by the LORD: and he delighteth in
> his way. (Psalm 37:23, KJV)
>
> And thine ears shall hear a word behind thee, saying, This is the way,
> walk ye in it, when ye turn to the right hand, and when ye turn to the
> left. (Isaiah 30:21, KJV)
>
> I will instruct thee and teach thee in the way which thou shalt go: I
> will guide thee with mine eye. (Psalm 32:8, KJV)

Sometimes God's guidance comes in the form of finances.  Sometimes applications are accepted or rejected, perhaps seemingly without justification.  Sometimes people may say things suggesting God's will for us--perhaps without realizing that they are doing so.  Sometimes we read something from the Bible, or God gives us an impression, that seems to point out our duty in bold print.  It is our place to pray in faith, then to move forward, then to accept the outcome as God's will, whether we may be at first pleased or not.  We cannot, however, expect for things to just happen while we sit idly by.  We must do our part to help answer our own prayers, for faith without works is dead (see James 2:17).

Those who truly seek God will find that their desires are given them of God, and God will, with the desire, make a way for its fulfillment.

> Delight thyself also in the LORD: and he shall give thee the desires
> of thine heart. Commit thy way unto the LORD; trust also in him; and
> he shall bring it to pass. (Psalm 37:4-5, KJV)

### Conclusion

Request, trust, and accept God's guidance, in faith.